# Many body physics - changing to $k$ space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform, many-body, second-quantization

I have an example in my notes starting with

> Linear Chain:
>   $$H=-t\sum_{\langle i i' \rangle} c_i^\dagger c_{i'} = -2t \sum_k c_k^\dagger c_k \cos{k}$$

I don't know where the $2 \cos{k}$ comes from.

Comment: You should define the different symbols. For example, what is the relation between $c_i$ and $c_k$?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform From my notes that is unclear

Comment: In that case you should take better notes. We cannot guess what the symbols mean.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform sorry these are printed ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up to a sign on the Fourier transform, the definition of $c_k$ is

$$
c_k =\frac{1}{\sqrt N}\sum_j e^{ikj}c_j
$$

You can get the formula for $c_k^\dagger$ by taking the conjugate of both sides. You can also invert the Fourier transform to get

$$
c_j =\frac{1}{\sqrt N}\sum_k e^{-ikj}c_k
$$

Again, you can take the conjugate of both sides to get the equation for $c_j^\dagger$. Proving your relation then just comes from plugging in the expressions for $c_j$ and $c_j^\dagger$ in terms of the $c_k$ and simplifying.